# can't activate multi_json (~> 0.0.5, runtime) for ["instagram-0.8"], already activated multi_json-1.0.3 for []

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, instagram

I am making an instagram application using rails, but I keep getting this error every time I start my application:

> can't activate multi_json (~> 0.0.5, runtime) for ["instagram-0.8"],
>   already activated multi_json-1.0.3 for []

My rails version is 3.0.4 and instagram gem has been installed (gem install instagram). What am i doing wrong?

Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should use bundler to manage your dependencies, rather than using rubygems directly.

If you use bundler, then execute your scripts with `bundle exec <usual command here>`, for example, `bundle exec rspec spec/`.

Bundler deals with all these issues for you.  You may have to uninstall the gems you have installed manually in order to get this error to go away, however.